# Database interaction logic

Tags: java, sql, android, sqlite

I have a database-intensive app, almost every activity requires access to the database, both reading and writing.
I had a lot of problems with separate threads and activities on the stack closing connections to the database when the current activity was using it, even if I opened and closed the database immediately before and after use.

So I opted to use a single instance of the database. Now I have no problems, but, is this right?

**Application class**

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application
{
    private DatabaseAdapter PrDatabaseAdapter; 

    public DatabaseAdapter getDatabaseAdapter()
    {
        return PrDatabaseAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        PrDatabaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
        PrDatabaseAdapter.open();
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**
The database adapter just sits on top of the `DatabaseManager` (my `SQLiteOpenHelper`)

```
private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private DatabaseManager dbManager;

/**
 * The DatabaseAdapter contains all interaction logic for the database
 * @param context
 */
public DatabaseAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

/**
 * Opens writable database
 * @return DatabaseAdapter;
 * @throws SQLiteException
 */
public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLiteException
{
    dbManager = new DatabaseManager(context);
    db = dbManager.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

/**
 * Closes database connection
 */
public void close()
{
    dbManager.close();
}
```

I'm still learning a lot about Java and Android and I would appreciate some insight to the pros and cons of this approach.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Android, so just some generic Java notes:

1. `PrDatabaseAdapter` should be `prDatabaseAdapter` (with lowercase first letter). See *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted naming conventions* and [The Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, 6.1 Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/):

   > Names of fields that are not final should be in mixed 
   >   case with a lowercase first letter and the first letters of subsequent words capitalized.
2. Javadoc comments like `@param context` aren't too useful, they say nothing more than the source code alone. I'd remove them.
3. Does it make sense to create a `DatabaseAdapter` with `null` `context`? I'd check this in the constructor and throw and `NullPointerException` if it's `null`. See *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 38: Check parameters for validity*